# Javascript method

Tags: javascript, methods

I am making a favorite list where you can add items through javascript and remove them again. The values are stored in cookies to remember the list when the user returns. The problem I have is that the method to remove the items from the list doesn't get run, unless there has been a postback first. My code to remove items look like this:

```
 function removeFavorite(OrderId) {
    debugger;
    var cookieValues = jQuery.cookie('FavoriteList');
    var cookieArray = cookieValues.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
        if (cookieArray[i] == OrderId) {
            cookieArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    jQuery('li#liFavoriteOrder_' + OrderId).remove();
    jQuery.cookie('FavoriteList', cookieArray.join(","));
}
```

and the code to call the method looks like this:

```
<a onclientclick="removeFavorite(1272331)" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

[image]

and the list looks like

```
<ul id="ulFavoriteList"> 
<li id="FavoriteId_1272331">
Milk
<a onclientclick="removeFavorite(1272331)" style="cursor: pointer;">
<img src="/Images/Icons/bullet_toggle_minus.png"/>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

The code to add to to the list looks a bit like this (short version):

```
        jQuery('<li id=\"liFavorite_' + OrderId + '\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"' + url + '\">' + OrderName + '</a><a style="cursor:pointer;" onclientclick="removeFavorite(' + OrderId+ ')"><img src="/Images/Icons/bullet_toggle_minus.png" /></a></li>').appendTo('ul#ulFavoriteList');
```

Answer (score 1):

This was just a very stupid error. I can't use onclientclick on regular html-elements, but need to use onclick instead.